# how to use jaxb external file mapping with jaxws and weblogic

Tags: web-services, jaxb, weblogic, jax-ws, moxy

So I'm working on application based on web service (JAXWS). I use some annotations like @WebService, @WebMethod ... 
I deploy my application in weblogic 12.1.3 as an EAR.

In my application, I have an interface that inherits from two interfaces and when I try to deploy my EAR in weblogic 12.1.3, I get this error message:

> Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20121116-8650760):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException Exception
>   Description: The java interface com.myapp.inter.Interface1 can not be
>   mapped by JAXB as it has multiple mappable parent interfaces. Multiple
>   inheritence is not supported

**My question:**
To solve this problem, I need to use MOXy's external mapping document to override the supertype of my interface like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="inter">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="Interface1" super-type="java.lang.Object"/>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

I do not know how to tell weblogic to use this file or where to put this file, I do not have a main method in my EAR.

My question focuses on how to use the jaxb external file with weblogic for my JAXWS Application

Please explain me step by step how to solve this problem

Comment: Same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458822/use-of-multiple-inheritance-in-eclipselink-moxy and more examples in this blog entry: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/07/oracle-weblogic-1212-now-with.html

Comment: I had already visited these links, my question focuses on how to use the jaxb external file with weblogic for my JAXWS Application

Comment: Another one of his answers shows how to load that file. Just package it in your ear or provide the full path outside of the ear. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318677/override-jaxb-binding-in-non-modifyable-domain-java-classes Specifically he unmarshalls the xml by doing a `File xml = new File("src/forum13318677/input.xml");`